# How can I convert my existing code by using one single hook useEffect

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In this code, I have used several useEffect() conditions how can I modify my code and convert it into a single condition using this code?

```
const ChannelDetailPage = () => {

const channel_id = param.query.index;

const [channelDetail, setChannelDetail] = useState([]);


 const fetchedData = useSelector((state) => state.ChannelDetail);

 const dispatch = useDispatch();

 useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getChannelDetail(channel_id));
 }, [channel_id]);

useEffect(() => {
 setChannelDetail(fetchedData.data);
 setLoading(fetchedData.isLoading);
}, [fetchedData]);
 return (
   <>
        <ChannelDetailCard
         key={channelDetail.id}
         id={channelDetail.id}
         data={channelDetail}
       />
    </>
 );
 };

 export default ChannelDetailPage;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using two different useEffect is actually better to keep the relevant logic together as it performs better.
If one data relies on another, I would probably fetch it in one useEffect to make sure that I have both things in place on time but if they are not then you should probably use a different useEffect.

Suppose I have a variable X and some changes are reflected when this variable changes so I would do something like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  //Some Code
}, [X])
```

Secondly if I have a variable Y and Z and some changes are reflected when this variable changes so I would do something like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  //Some Code
}, [Y, Z])
```

I would not do it like this because it would make the component re-render on any of the variables to change.

```
useEffect(() => {
  //Some Code
}, [X, Y, Z])
```

So it depends on your case if X, Y and Z are related put them in one if unrelated separate them.